# Template based Linked List - What should be Returned in search operation?

Tags: c++, templates

I am working with Templates and defined the below templated ListNode.

```
template <typename T>
class ListNode{
    private :
    public:
        ListNode *left;
        ListNode *right;
        T data;
        ListNode(T data){ this->data = data; }
};
```

If I implement the search Operation on this Linked list with the below prototype what should be the return value of the function. If T is a pointer, I can return NULL, but if T is a Complete object, what should be the return type, and how can i differentiate if T is a pointer or a Complete object. How can this search function works for T where T can be a pointer Or a complete object.

```
T List_search(T srch_data);

    T List_search(T srch_data) {

        ListNode<T> *curr = head;
         while (curr) {
            if (comp_fn.compare_data (curr->data, srch_data) == 0)
                return curr->data;
            curr = curr->right;
        }
        return NULL;                   <<< Compilation error if T is complete object 
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the C++ standard library for inspiration and how it signals absence in search (named "find") methods. BTW: What difference does it make that your code is a template? Further, even a list of pointers could contain a null pointer. How would you distinguish that from "not found"?

Comment: *If T is a pointer, I can return NULL, but if T is a Complete object* -- Your code shouldn't care what type `T` is.   If it does, then there is a flaw in your design.  If `T` is a pointer or object, the code should just work.  Let the user who decides to use pointers as the data type in the linked list worry about using pointers as the data type.

Comment: @AbhishekSagar -- If you return `&item`, it doesn't matter what `T` is.  Then it's up to the client to test for null, or dereference the pointer to get the object.  Then your code would magically "work" if you return `nullptr` if the object cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to keep things simple: return the address of the found item, and `nullptr` if the item cannot be found:

```
   template <typename T>
   T* List_search(T srch_data) 
   {
        ListNode<T> *curr = head;
         while (curr) 
         {
            if (comp_fn.compare_data (curr->data, srch_data) == 0)
                return &curr->data;
            curr = curr->right;
         }
         return nullptr;
   }
```

The client would then check for a `nullptr`, and if it isn't a `nullptr`, can dereference the pointer.

For example, if the linked list node holds an `int` type:

```
int* foundData = List_search(10)
if ( foundData )
{
    std::cout << *foundData;
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. That is a nice trick. It solves the problem/ Curious, is it a common approach used in STL or otherwise as @Ulrich suggested to look into STL implementation.

Comment: Basically, this approach is what the STL does.  Not as sophisticated, but similar.